# How to establish query for error signin in php

Tags: php

This is my signin query for PHP. I want when a user gives wrong answer , that the user is redirected to an error website. How can I do that?

```
<?php

    session_start();



    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "";
    $con =  new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $db_username, $db_password);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $query = $con->prepare(" SELECT username FROM faceflow WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
        $query->execute(array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => $_POST['password']
        ));
        $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $results[0]['username'];
        header('Location: /test/membership/loggedin.php');
    }
    else
    {
        die("Die hacker!");
    }



?>
```

Comment: Replace your `die()` with `header()`? *Seems logical.*

Comment: @Fred-ii- nope. doesnt work.

Comment: the person that voted down, I would also like to hear your opinion.

Comment: Don't store plain-text (or encypted...) passwords, use salted hashes.

Comment: Ok then, `if(!results){ // redirect }`

Comment: Your logic is wrong, the `else` is part of the `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`. Check if a row is found and redirect if not.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing @jeroen

Comment: Right, what @Fred-ii- said......

Comment: Sidenote about password storage: Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Comment: Get rid of your `else{...}` (*or do something else with it*) and add `if(!results){ header('Location: /test/membership/noaccess.php'); }` @user3504631

Comment: I made a slight mistake earlier, and forgot the `$` sign in `if(!results){` which should have read as `if(!$results){` but see my answer below. @user3504631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, it worked for me.

Sidenotes: Both `header()` have been commented out for testing purposes.

`noaccess.php` is a filename example.

```
<?php
session_start();

    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "";
    $con =  new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $db_username, $db_password);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $query = $pdo->prepare(" SELECT username FROM faceflow WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
        $query->execute(array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => $_POST['password']
        ));
        $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($results){

        $_SESSION['username'] = $results[0]['username'];
    // header('Location: /test/membership/loggedin.php');

    echo "You have access";

    }

    if(!$results){
    // header('Location: /test/membership/noaccess.php');
    echo "Sorry";
    }



    }
```

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you are storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)